# Pjax with wordpress custom theme giving 301 error in firebug

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pjax

I am trying to use pjax in  wordpress . but whenever I try to click the link which fetches the content via ajax call , nothing happens and page loads normally, firebug console show 301 aborted error . Any one can help ?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using ajax in wordpress then make the **action** in function.php file of your theam , like below example

```
add_action('wp_ajax_do_ajax', 'our_ajax_function');
function our_ajax_function(){
     // now we'll write what the server should do with our request here
}
```

Hope it will Help :)

Comment: Thanks hRaval , but this is for normal ajax request in wordpress I think , I am using pjax.

Comment: check your path is correct Be sure it's the public facing path. Otherwise post more of your code and we can debug further.