# Using recaptcha on php form within Wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I'm using the following to send a form to an email address. I want to incorporate recaptcha but want to adjust it slightly.

1) If the captcha isn't filled in I want the error to pop up as an alert box.

2) If the captcha was filled in correctly, then it should reload the page showing the thank you message (that's at the bottom of the script below).

3) Rather than check the verify.php file, I want it to check it on this page. (I replaced the permalink in the action with a link to the verify.php file - which I don't want to do!)

```
        <form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <table border="0" style="float:left;" width="490">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p>Company Name:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p>Your Name:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p>E-mail:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p>Telephone:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" /></td>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table border="0" style="float:left;" width="490">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><p style="margin-right:47px;margin-top:7px;">Enquiry:</p></td>
                        <td><textarea name="enquiry"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateCaptcha()
{
    if ($('input[name="valid"]')) return true;
    if ($('input[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').val() == "")
    {
        alert("Please complete the CAPTCHA field.");
        return false
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.medilogicuk.com/wp-content/themes/default/verify.php",
        type: "POST",
        async:"false",
        data: {
            recaptcha_response_field: $('input[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').val(),
            recaptcha_challenge_field: $('input[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "OK")
            {
                $('input[name="valid"]').val(1);
                $('.form').submit();
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("An error occured, please try again later");
        }
    });
    return false;
};
</script>


                <?php require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $publickey = "(my key)"; // you got this from the signup page
  echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message">Send message</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>        

        <? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

        $to = "(my email)";
        $header = 'From: (company email)';
        $subject = "Website enquiry";
        $companyname_field = $_POST['companyname'];
        $fullname_field = $_POST['fullname'];
        $email_field = $_POST['email'];
        $tel_field = $_POST['tel'];
        $enquiry_field = $_POST['enquiry'];


        $body = "Hello,\n\n You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n Name: $fullname_field\n Company Name: $companyname_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Tel: $tel_field\n Message:\n $enquiry_field\n\n Please reply to the enquiry asap.\n\n Kind Regards \n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

        echo "</br><p style=\"color:#e41770!IMPORTANT;\">Thank you for getting in touch, we will contact you shortly.</p>";

        } ?>
        </form>
```

This is in my verify.php file:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "(my key)";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) 
{
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again. (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} 
else 
{
    echo "OK";
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Here is a solution which i commented there. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405560/wordpress-recaptcha-use-on-form-that-created-using-page

Answer (score 2):

Form changes

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="index.php" onsubmit="return validateCaptcha()">
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="0" />
```

Below the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateCaptcha()
{
    if ($('input[name="valid"]')) return true;
    if ($('input[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').val() == "")
    {
        alert("Fill in the captcha field");
        return false
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "verify.php",
        type: "POST",
        async:"false",
        data: {
            recaptcha_response_field: $('input[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').val(),
            recaptcha_challenge_field: $('input[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "OK")
            {
                $('input[name="valid"]').val(1);
                $('.form').submit();
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("An error occured, please try again later");
        }
    });
    return false;
};
</script>
```

verify.php

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) 
{
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again. (reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} 
else 
{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that it's not actually checking if the captcha is filled in correctly. If you just type anything in it just sends the email anyways.

Comment: Ok it now verifies if the answer is incorrect (wrong link to the verify file!), the alert pops up but when you click ok it then sends the email. Obviously don't want it to send the email if the captcha was entered wrongly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Gave that a try and it now doesn't validate when you put the correct words in (tried it a few times). Here's the actual form - http://www.medilogicuk.com/contact/

Comment: Thanks but it's still sending the email even when the captcha is filled in incorrectly.

Comment: @hRaval I've added that but again, email gets sent even if the captcha is filled in incorrectly. I've updated my question to show exactly what I have.

Comment: i think you do above code for wordpress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134915/pjax-with-wordpress-custom-theme-giving-301-error-in-firebug/11134989#11134989 will help

Comment: @hRaval Would it be possible to put that in the answer to work with my code?