# Wordpress Recaptcha use on form that created using page

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I am trying to use a wordpress recaptcha plugin.

The plugin (like wp-recaptcah, better Wp recaptcha) that I am trying to use is only working for the comment form.

But in my case I have created a page and there I have inserted HTML that is managed from the admin panel.

I don't understand how I can use the plugin with my form.

I did not get any shortcode HTML tag to use it directly on the page.

Any suggestion how I can achieve this?

I have created a page in the admin panel and inserted this code. My form is submitted via AJAX:

```
<div class="First"> Here some static Html is used </div>

<form id="main-form">
    <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input class="span6" type="text" maxlength="45" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input class="span6" type="text" maxlength="45" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input class="span6" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea class="span12" name="message" rows="6" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn >Send Enquiry</button></div>
</form>

<div class="second">Here some static Html is used </div>
```

Comment: We don't even know [which ReCaptcha](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=recaptcha) plugin you are referring to...

Comment: You might want to link us to the plugin... there are tons of recaptcha plugins for wp

Comment: @brasofilo,@xlordt:any plugin which is supporting recaptcha like wp-recaptcha ,wprdpress better captcha

Comment: @xlordt wp-recaptcha or wordpress better recaptcha plugin.

Comment: Ahh yes, I tried these plugins before.. prob is these plugins have no kind of shortcodes and r some what not well coded, but I will see what I can do for you today or tom.. now are you creating this form by hand? meaning as a script? or are you creating a post/page in the dashboard?

Comment: @xlordt Now i have created form by post/page in the dashboard.but if you have better solution will go for that.

Comment: Ok, see what happens if you add this to a script

$recaptcha = new reCAPTCHA('recaptcha_options');
$recaptcha->show_recaptcha_in_comments ();

if not, I will deal with it later today.. I have a friend taht requested this as well. this is wp-reCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion: use [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and [Contact Form 7 reCAPTCHA Extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-recaptcha-extension/) or the [Really Simple Captcha](http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-captcha/) plugin, both work well with Contact Form 7.

You'll create the form on the CF7 admin page, then insert it into your WordPress page with a shortcode, which, for many reasons, is much better than writing the form itself in the WordPress text view.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [HoneyPot](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-honeypot/) extension + BadBehavior + Akismet/AntispamBee. If no spam comes in, perfect. Otherwise, use the dreadful recap thing.

Comment: I'd agree with that too-- sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use reCAPTCHA Form . It give u a form along with the recaptcha.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/recaptcha-form/

or else you may be wanting the following one instead,
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha/